# Mysql query into Eloquent

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm converting roject from pure PHP to Laravel 4, and I have a problem with converting this query

```
SELECT * FROM verses,thoughts WHERE verses.id != thoughts.verses_id
```

I have two tables verse and thought. one verse has one thought. when creating a thought i want to display all the verse whose thoughts has not been created . Im using Laravel 4.2 display the verses it is not listed in thoughts

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: Convert this query into Eloquent ORM LARAVEL 4

Comment: Okay, so what have you tried and what was the result? what did you expect? were there errors?

Comment: I have two tables verse and thought. Im using Laravel 4.2 display the verses it is not listed in thoughts

Comment: Laravel provides 'raw' access to the database: see: [laravel-raw-queries](http://fideloper.com/laravel-raw-queries). Internet search: 'laravel raw query'.

Comment: I have two tables verse and thought. one verse has one thought. when creating a thought i want to display all the verse whose thoughts has not been created . Im using Laravel 4.2 display the verses it is not listed in thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Did you read [the docs](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queries#joins)?

```
DB::table('thoughts')
    ->join('verses', 'verses.id', '!=', 'thoughts.verses_id')
    ->get();
```

Comment: Did you? That's Fluent, not Eloquent. :-p Eloquent would begin with `Thought::join(...`.

Comment: Since he didn't "try" anything per-se I'm not giving him the answer. It's a starting point. Plus all chained methods work the same in Eloquent as per the docs.

Comment: Post it as a comment then, not an **answer**.